# Connect bool topics - node required?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, topic, remap, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey folks,

do I actually need a node to translate a boolean topic into two others?

I've got subscribed topic `/input` and two published topics `/out1` and `/out2`. All message are boolean, `/out1` shall republish `/input` and `/out2` shall republish *NOT* `/input`. So if there's a True coming in on `/input`, `/out1` shall publish True and `/out2` shall publish False.

Is there a way to achieve that without writing a node? Some sort of remapping or something?

Thank you, guys!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/169896/connect-bool-topics---node-required?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2014-05-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Remapping only changes the name of a topic; not the data types involved.

You can do the mapping of `/input` to `/out1` with remapping arguments, but you'll need to write a node to do the inversion between `/input` and `/out2`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2014-05-26**:
Would be an interesting addition for roslaunch, doesn't it? You could create truth-table like connections between topics. Some kind of value mapping could also be achieved by it instead of having to write nodes for each of this purposes. Would reduce some overhead, I'd guess...

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-26**:
The trouble is that this isn't directly a roslaunch proposal, since all roslaunch is doing is passing remapping arguments to the underlying rospy and roscpp libraries. Instead, you'd have to extend the remapping syntax to support arbitrary data modification/remapping.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-26**:
You're welcome to propose this as a feature request against the ros_comm bug tracker, but I think it is unlikely to go very far.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-26**:
As an alternative, you could write your subscriber node so that it takes an additional `invert` parameter and uses that to decide whether or not to invert the incoming data. If you need this a lot, you could wrap it up in a class and namespace the invert parameter to node/topic/invert or something.